# Terraform Snowpipe on Azure error on integration

Tags: azure, terraform, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowpipe

I'm trying to set up snowpipe with terraform on azure using https://registry.terraform.io/providers/chanzuckerberg/snowflake/latest/docs/resources/pipe#optional

my resource looks like this:

```
resource "snowflake_pipe" "pipe" {
  provider = snowflake.sys_admin
  integration = "myintegration"
  database = "mydb"
  schema   = "PUBLIC"
  name     = "mypipe"

  comment = "A pipe."


  copy_statement = "copy into \"db\".\"schema\".\"table\" from (select $1,$2,$3,$4,$5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, metadata$filename, metadata$file_row_number, current_timestamp  from   @db.PUBLIC.stage (file_format => TEST.PUBLIC.CSV))"
  auto_ingest    = true

}
```

when I run terraform apply I get:

`An argument named "integration" is not expected here.`

If I remove `integration = "myintegration"` from above I get:

`Pipe Notifications bind failure "Integration cannot be null for Azure."`

Has anyone managed to go around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `integration` argument was added to the resource schema in [this commit](https://github.com/chanzuckerberg/terraform-provider-snowflake/commit/28bdf96b5a0bf4c88e41f93af2e93c5b513ebd58) on June 4, 2021. The provider is lacking a full CHANGELOG, so we have to use the general timeline estimates for versions from the provider registry. In that case, it would appear that you would need to upgrade your provider version to at least `0.25.0` to support this functionality.